# Cocoon data-association-insertion-node with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

According https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#link_to_add_association you should be able to pass a function to `data-association-insertion-node`

I have tried this:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Timeslot', f, :timeslots, :data => {'association-insertion-node' => 'get_row()'} %>
```

And this:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Timeslot', f, :timeslots, :data => {'association-insertion-node' => 'get_row'} %>
```

And this (getting desperate):

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Timeslot', f, :timeslots, :data => {'association-insertion-node' => 'function get_row(node){var row = "<tr></tr>";$("#table_body").append(row);return row;}'} %>
```

But none of them work.

Javascript:

```
function get_row(node){
    var row = "<tr></tr>"
    $("#table_body").append(row);
    return row
}
```

I am trying to add a `tr` to a `table` and then append the nested timeslot form to the `tr`.

Comment: Can you first explain what real world problem you are attempting to solve?    I can see from the 3rd option, you clearly tried to eliminate the possibility of the file not being loaded.  Did the code work before you put it in a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible what you are trying to do. When setting the `data-association-insertion-method` like this, it will just be a string in javascript, and not a reference to a method.

As [documented](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#control-the-insertion-behaviour) in the README, you have to do the following (assuming you gave your links a class `.add-timeslot`):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(".add-timeslot a").
    data("association-insertion-method", 'append').
    data("association-insertion-node", function(link){
      return link.closest('.row').next('.row').find('.sub_tasks_form')
    });
});
```

(the example is almost verbatim copied from documention for demonstration purposes only --you will have to fill in your `get_row` function)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the README.